# Set four menu items in single row

Tags: android, menu

I have a menu(that comes when the user clicks default menu button) in which i have four items. So iam using following code to display menu. Problem is four items come in two rows(2x2). Is it possible to display in a single row.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.editshare, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

menu/editshare.xml

```
    <item android:id="@+id/item1"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon"
          android:title="item1" />
      <item android:id="@+id/item2"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon"
          android:title="item" />
      <item android:id="@+id/item3"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon"
          android:title="item3" />
     <item android:id="@+id/item4"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon"
          android:title="item4" />


</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

http://androidworkz.com/2011/02/04/custom-menu-bar-tabs-how-to-hook-the-menu-button-to-showhide-a-custom-tab-bar/

Comment: @Seshu: In this case 'tabs' means the sort found in a `TabHost`. It has nothing to do with tablet devices.

Comment: That's the one you need. You have to build your own menu.

Answer (score 2):

i think this is not possible with default menu, But you can create one custom menu type and show it when menu button is pressed. and hide when select any option.

You can say it is one transparent slider which pop up when you click menu button. And hide it when option selected or again menu is pressed...

Comment: Nice idea +1. Yes, if you can trap the MENU button and use something like a `SlidingDrawer` with a `LinearLayout` with 4 buttons as content. Just make it so the `SlidingDrawer` has no handle and control the slide up/down in code.

Answer (score 0):

Its default behavior of android menu items, and it can not be altered.

Answer (score 0):

It's called common usability :P You have to think that Android is very smart so it will display in 2 rows on phones with a lower res/density and in a single row on a phone (or orientation) with bigger res/density :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't display four menus in a single row in android. This is controlled by the system. 
You can use four buttons with layout_weight= "1.0" but this will use your UI space.